# RODBC: Columns and values don't match

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, rodbc

I came across this behavior in RODBC (using SQL Server driver):

```
df1 = data.frame(matrix(c(1:20), nrow=10))
df1
```

which outputs

```
   X1 X2
1   1 11
2   2 12
3   3 13
4   4 14
5   5 15
6   6 16
7   7 17
8   8 18
9   9 19
10 10 20
```

which makes sense. Then I save the table using RODBC

```
sqlSave(conout, df1, 'TEST')
```

Then I switch the two created columns:

```
df2 = df1[,c(2,1)]
df2
```

which outputs

```
   X2 X1
1  11  1
2  12  2
3  13  3
4  14  4
5  15  5
6  16  6
7  17  7
8  18  8
9  19  9
10 20 10
```

which also makes sense.

Seeing those two tables, I see that X1 only contains 1:10 and X2 only contains 11:20. Now, when I do

```
sqlSave(conout, df2, 'TEST', append=TRUE, fast=FALSE)
sqlQuery(conout, 'SELECT * FROM TEST')

   rownames X1 X2
1         1  1 11
2         2  2 12
3         3  3 13
4         4  4 14
5         5  5 15
6         6  6 16
7         7  7 17
8         8  8 18
9         9  9 19
10       10 10 20
11        1 11  1
12        2 12  2
13        3 13  3
14        4 14  4
15        5 15  5
16        6 16  6
17        7 17  7
18        8 18  8
19        9 19  9
20       10 20 10
```

which is definitely not what I saved. Now three questions:

1. How is this possible?
2. Where is this behavior explained in the RODBC manual?
3. How can I prevent the behavior without reordering my columns (the real case behind this example has > 300 columns).

Comment: I do not understand your question. It looks to me like exactly what you saved. The first 10 rows are df1. Then the next 10 rows are df2 which you appended. What answer did you expect to get?

Comment: I think you answered your own question in 3, you have to reorder your columns to match the order of the columns in the database.